# How to prevent command key's default OS behavior using Love2d (LÖVE) or Lua

Tags: lua, love2d

Is there a way to prevent the default OS behavior for a command key (i.e. prevent start menu opening and focus loss when the windows key is pressed) using Love2d (LÖVE) in particular, or Lua more generally.  If I understand correctly, LÖVE uses LuaJIT, so it would be helpful if a Lua based approach did not involve Lua 5.2/5.3 functions that are not implemented in LuaJIT, but I could rebuild with the appropriate module or shim the LÖVE interpreter if necessary.

Having failed to find a simple solution on my own, I'm currently thinking I will have to create a Lua-C Module.  If that is the case, any advice/links along those lines would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lua *certainly* has no functionality for hijacking OS key functionality of this kind. Such things are too OS-specific for Lua to expose. And from its documentation, Love2D has no such functionality either.

While we're on the subject:

> prevent start menu opening and focus loss when the windows key is pressed

It would be *exceedingly rude* to have your application prevent basic OS functionality like this from working. However good your game may be, it is *not* as important as the user being able to do what they actually want. If the user wants to switch to something else, that's their right, and you should not interfere. If the user accidentally pressed that button, that's their responsibility.

The only thing you should do is set up [a `love.focus` callback](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.focus), so that when the application loses focus you can automatically pause.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had basically come to the same conclusion on Lua/Love2d support for this behavior. I will have to start reading about Lua-C Modules. I already implemented logic to pause when the love window loses focus. I appreciate and understand your philosophical point of view on whether a game _should_ be able hijack this behavior or not. I would expose this as an option to the user, with the default OS behavior being the default.  I want to create an interface that my young son can use without inadvertently shutting down the computer (as he has before, surprisingly quickly).

Comment: @EricLease: If you're going to start shelling out to arbitrary code, don't bother with Lua-C modules. Love2D uses LuaJIT for several reasons. But one of the most useful is that LuaJIT has an FFI mechanism that allows it to load *any* DLL and access it directly from Lua code. So you don't need to lean how to write code that knows it's talking to Lua. You just need to write a regular DLL, then have your LuaJIT code load it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If you wouldn't mind adding that to your answer I will mark it accepted. If I'm successful, I may post an answer with exactly how I accomplished the desired behavior, but you essentially answered my question. That being said, I also discovered [Start Killer](http://www.startkiller.com/) which would do all the heavy lifting for me. I'm considering using that in conjunction with `os.execute()` if it's not as simple as trapping the keypress and discarding it.  I'm wary of that approach though since I don't know how the author is accomplishing it, or if it's safe.